# Can I use plurals in scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

Can plural form of words be used in the scrabble? For example, table, obviously can. But can I extend it to the "tables" for example?

Comment: I recommend the following website to check the validity of a word during a game.  One downside of looking up a word in a dictionary during a challenge is that you will (accidentally) see the valid suffixes, giving you an unfair advantage.  This website will, by default, only tell you "yes" or "no" when you type in the challenged word.  You can see the definition with another click.  http://scrabblewordfinder.org/dictionary-checker

Comment: I would downvote, as this question's answer could easily be found online.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics, That's your prerogative, but that doesn't help this site, which is the whole point of the vote system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

> Any word that is found in a standard English dictionary can be used in the game of Scrabble. There are also Official Scrabble Dictionaries that can be purchased for more word options. ([Rules source](http://www.scrabblepages.com/scrabble/rules/))

Any word found in a standard English dictionary is allowed, which includes plural words.

You can look up a word to see if it is legal [here](http://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary), and searching "tables" shows it is legal.

Comment: As I remember it you can't add an "s" to pluralise an existing word as the *only* thing you do on your go. But a quick bit of googling reveals nothing, so maybe that was a house rule.

Comment: @AndyT Yeah it could have been. As I remember playing Scrabble, it was a common move to do nothing but add an "s" to an existing word.

Comment: @AndyT That's not actually in the official rules of scrabble but it is a popular  (and in my opinion, good) house rule.